# How to change property value in array object with array values in javascript

Tags: javascript

How to change property in the object array based on array of values in javascript,

I have object `obj` and parameter as `list`, should changed the property `checked` to true, if title matched with the list in javascript

if the title is matched with list and has children, then checked: true
ie.`countries title is matched with list , then children also change the property checked: true`

if the children title is matched , then change checked: true for that object only
ie.`clothes title is matched with list , then change the property checked: true` for that object only

I stuck to do with list of arrays as param,

```js
var obj = [{
  title: "Sample",
  checked: false,
  children: [{
      title: "products",
      checked: false,
      children: [{
          title: "clothes",
          id: 1,
          checked: false
        },
        {
          title: "electronics",
          id: 2,
          checked: false
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      title: "countries",
      checked: false,
      children: [{
          title: "IN",
          id: 1,
          checked: false
        },
        {
          title: "TH",
          id: 2,
          checked: false
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}];

var list = ["clothes", "countries"];
```

Expected Output:

```
[{
    title: "Sample",
    checked: false,
    children: [
    {
    title: "products", 
    checked: false,
    children: [
        {title: "clothes", id: 1, checked: true},
        {title: "electronics", id: 2, checked: false}
      ]
    },{
    title: "countries", 
    checked: true,
    children: [
        {title: "IN", id: 1, checked: true},
        {title: "TH", id: 2, checked: true}
      ]
    }
    ]
  }]
```

Comment: your code is non-working and has invalid syntax, such as using a string instead of a parameter name in changeProperty and using a list as a parameter when your function expects a string

Comment: How is `{title: "clothes", id: 1, checked: true}`? The title is Product

Comment: @user120242, as you suggested, it is not working and it requires much refinements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some recursion, to handle any depth of nesting:

With this solution, it is very generic, you can change the childrenProp, matchProp, checkedProp etc. and it will allow you to search as deep as you need to in a nested structure.

```js
const obj = [
  {
    title: "Sample",
    checked: false,
    children: [
      {
        title: "products", 
        checked: false,
        children: [
          {title: "clothes", id: 1, checked: false},
          {title: "electronics", id: 2, checked: false}
        ]
      },
      {
        title: "countries", 
        checked: false,
        children: [
          {title: "IN", id: 1, checked: false},
          {title: "TH", id: 2, checked: false}
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];

var list=["clothes", "countries"];
checkPropertyForMatch(obj, list);
console.log(obj);
checkPropertyForMatch(obj, ['electronics']);
console.log(obj);

function checkPropertyForMatch(inputArr, matchList, matchProp, childrenProp, checkedProp){
  //default params, or they can be overwritten:
  matchProp = matchProp || 'title';
  childrenProp = childrenProp || 'children';
  checkedProp = checkedProp || 'checked';
  
  innerRecursive(inputArr, matchList);
  
  //recursively search the nested object:
  function innerRecursive(currArr, list){
    for (item of currArr){
      if ( list.includes(item[matchProp]) ){
        item[checkedProp] = true;
        if (item[childrenProp]){
          //this parent matched, so mark all children as marked too:
          markAllChildrenChecked(item[childrenProp]);
        }
      }
      else {
        item[checkedProp] = false;
        if (item[childrenProp]) {
          //it didn't match but it has children, so search them too:
          innerRecursive(item[childrenProp], list)
        }  
      }
    }  
  }
  
  //this recursively marks all children as checked = true:
  function markAllChildrenChecked(currArr){
    for (item of currArr){
      item[checkedProp] = true;
      if (item[childrenProp]){
        markAllChildrenChecked(item[childrenProp]);
      }  
    }  
  }
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Output:

```js
[
  {
    "title": "Sample",
    "checked": false,
    "children": [
      {
        "title": "products",
        "checked": false,
        "children": [
          {"title": "clothes", "id": 1, "checked": true},
          {"title": "electronics", "id": 2, "checked": false}
        ]
      },
      {
        "title": "countries",
        "checked": true,
        "children": [
          {"title": "IN", "id": 1, "checked": true},
          {"title": "TH", "id": 2, "checked": true}
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: thanks for solution, but if i pass another list `[electronics]` , previous list[countries, clothes], should be false, new list should be true only

Comment: Oh you want to also mark fields false then when they don't match, that's possible, see updated answer.

Answer (score -1):

The trick here is below:

```
if (list.indexOf(ele.title) > -1 || list.indexOf(el.title) > -1) {
    el.checked = true;
}
```

```js
var obj = [{
  title: "Sample",
  checked: false,
  children: [{
      title: "products",
      checked: false,
      children: [{
          title: "clothes",
          id: 1,
          checked: false
        },
        {
          title: "electronics",
          id: 2,
          checked: false
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      title: "countries",
      checked: false,
      children: [{
          title: "IN",
          id: 1,
          checked: false
        },
        {
          title: "TH",
          id: 2,
          checked: false
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}];
var list = ["clothes", "countries"];


obj.forEach(elem => {
  elem.children.forEach(ele => {
    ele.children.forEach(el => {
      if (list.indexOf(ele.title) > -1 || list.indexOf(el.title) > -1) {
        el.checked = true;
      }
    })
  })
})

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: output is incorrect.  does not handle case where ele.title matches

Comment: Handles. See the output.

Comment: countries is false in your output